# Python return a list of slices to print based on maxchars string-length boundary

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

```
stringlist = ['aanbetaal', 'aanbetaald', 'aanbetaalde', 'aanbetaalden', 'aanbetaalt', 'aanbetalen', 'aanbetaling', 'aanbetalingen', 'aanbeten', 'aanbeter', 'aanbeval', 'aanbevalen', 'aanbeveel', 'aanbeveelt', 'aanbevelen', 'aanbevelend', 'aanbevelende', 'aanbevelenswaard', 'aanbevelenswaardig', 'aanbevelenswaardige', 'aanbevelenswaardiger', 'aanbeveling', 'aanbevelingen', 'aanbevelingsbrief', 'aanbevelingsbriefje', 'aanbevelingsbrieven', 'aanbevelingscomité', 'aanbevelingscomités', 'aanbevolen', 'aanbevolenen', 'aanbid', 'aanbiddelijk', 'aanbiddelijke', 'aanbiddelijker', 'aanbiddelijkst', 'aanbiddelijkste', 'aanbidden', 'aanbiddend', 'aanbiddende', 'aanbidder', 'aanbidders', 'aanbidding', 'aanbiddingen', 'aanbiddingsleider', 'aanbiddingsleiders', 'aanbiddingslied', 'aanbiddingsteam', 'aanbidster', 'aanbidsters', 'aanbidt', 'aanbied', 'aanbieden', 'aanbiedend', 'aanbiedende', 'aanbieder', 'aanbieders', 'aanbiedersmarkt', 'aanbiedgedrag', 'aanbieding', 'aanbiedingen', 'aanbiedingsbrief', 'aanbiedingsbrieven', 'aanbiedingsfolder', 'aanbiedingsfolders', 'aanbiedingsnota', 'aanbiedingsplicht', 'aanbiedingsprijs', 'aanbiedingsprijzen', 'aanbiedingsvorm', 'aanbiedingsvormen', 'aanbiedstation', 'aanbiedt', 'aanbijt', 'aanbijten', 'aanbind', 'aanbinden', 'aanbindt', 'aanblaas', 'aanblaast']

maxchars = 150
runningcount = 0
tmpslice = []

for i, item in enumerate(stringlist):
    runningcount += len(item)
    if runningcount <= int(maxchars):
        tmpslice.append(i)
    else:
        yield tmpslice
        tmpslice = [i]
        runningcount = len(item)
yield(tmpslice)
```

I try to generate strings with a boundary of max characters. But I want only full words inside the list.

My expected output looks like this:

```
tmpslice = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
            [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
            [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33],
            [34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 47],
            [48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60],
            [61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68],
            [69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78]
           ]
```

Each list should contain as many item until variable maxchars is reached. The code above returns yield outside function. I'm new to programming and Python I can't figure out why.

Hopefully someone knows how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I understand what you're telling about using a function. I tried the first solution and that seems to work pretty fine. I will take a look at the other solutions. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a function, so you can't make a generator (`yield` is used to implement generator functions; when you call such a function, it returns an iterator that, when iterated over, runs the function until a `yield`, produces a result, then pauses until the next item is requested). If you just want to `print` it, do `print(tmpslice)`. Changing the code to:

```
stringlist = [...]

maxchars = 150
runningcount = 0
tmpslice = []

for i, item in enumerate(stringlist):
    runningcount += len(item)
    if runningcount <= int(maxchars):
        tmpslice.append(i)
    else:
        print(tmpslice)
        tmpslice = [i]
        runningcount = len(item)
print(tmpslice)
```

mostly gets the output you're looking for. If you want it packaged up in a `list`, you'd do:

```
stringlist = [...]

maxchars = 150
runningcount = 0
tmpslice = []
allslices = []

for i, item in enumerate(stringlist):
    runningcount += len(item)
    if runningcount <= int(maxchars):
        tmpslice.append(i)
    else:
        allslices.append(tmpslice)
        tmpslice = [i]
        runningcount = len(item)
allslices.append(tmpslice)
print(allslices)
```

so each new `tmpslice` is stored to a single `list` which you `print` at the end.

Lastly, if you want to use `yield`, you'd just make a proper generator function and call it:

```python
stringlist = [... omitted for brevity ...]

def make_slices(strings, maxchars):
    runningcount = 0
    tmpslice = []

    for i, item in enumerate(strings):
        runningcount += len(item)
        if runningcount <= int(maxchars):
            tmpslice.append(i)
        else:
            yield tmpslice
            tmpslice = [i]
            runningcount = len(item)
    yield tmpslice

for slc in make_slices(stringlist, 150):
    print(slc)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZVRbtswDIbfcwq9JcGCoUWxl2E5SVEMqkUnTGTZEBlv7Y12jh0slZImImXXT/o/kb9IQlGGN9734el8Jo4Ydh6JzdY8L60Nr8DW@uXGFOG0gkoGpVkor/Z8OqmScl@t4309imJG5TgCeCVYKB2YlKskaE1/rI1ujuFunsIXOEouW75KXVcC9BoR2ll4gDk8Ti2avkP@/@8LTIX3ai5ZFY2urFwyOBxrDRMQa0I8JSotKOG0UpHKO5JQYqpXpVxz5x5QGxRINUVwFWKwXUHE0ikrYVHaFS4g2wTVJug2QVYJqrqL6mw8yiN24KLdCSBHAdUoLlpfL8HGSWTbe11OgVTR0LOt0OCx2XMNIx5ohr1PDh/72M0gFUdsGXtJynkHuRRZYvbBKX5P8NaSXPPyZbFw0JrOHuF3uiAN0Or6UtImwb/N3kZa/1yY9MVTCGmj6U8hv6EPF8jdcEnLj2ryyqjto8GNQYbOYDAQTh1Ey3Az/rSbWH7bmvQrXeW89T0CWx30a5s8eVWVdvtu1Xy3w5Bu3wqLEXgCHfyG4N09ZdYnd4Uvaquagq64slzkUZBv8himE87/RRvz@OPhs4l0W1JnKXx9Pn8A)

The loop at over `make_slices` could be changed to `allslices = list(make_slices(stringlist, 150))` if you want a `list` rather than printing them out.

Comment: You don't really need `int(...)` in `int(maxchars)` - like nowhere it's always inputted as `int` anyways...